# Pass an Bitmap Arraylist to Another Activity GridView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have in my **MainActivity** Function to apply some transformations on image(s) and then add every single image to editedImage which is `private List<Bitmap> editedImages;` but  when i try to pass the image(s) to my other activity which is **EditedImagesActivity** by this function :

```
    private void displayEditedImages() {
    if (!editedImages.isEmpty()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditedImagesActivity.class);

        // Convert the byte arrays to Bitmap objects
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>(editedImages);
        // Pass the edited images as an ArrayList of Bitmap objects
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("editedImages", bitmaps);


        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i am getting an empty gridView!
how can i receive data correctly so i can add image(s) to gridView ?
MY **EditedImagesActivity** :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    try {
        editedImages = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("editedImages");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // The edited images were not found
        Log.e("EditedImagesActivity", "The edited images were not found", e);
        return;
    }
    if (editedImages == null || editedImages.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("EditedImagesActivity", "The edited images were not found");
        return;
    }
    GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(new BitmapAdapter(this, editedImages));
```

Not: i am getting "The edited images were not found" in logcat.

Comment: Show how do you get the images from intent in `EditedImagesActivity`.

Comment: Recently i added it.

Comment: _**Convert the byte arrays to Bitmap objects**_ You mean converting `byte[][]` to `Bitmap` list? Probably you get the `bitmaps` `null` in this line: `ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>(editedImages);`.